# An interesting way of deriving the Stirling formula

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, approximation

**Question**

1. I would first like to show that the equality below holds:
   $$ -1 + \frac{1}{2}\left( 2k+1 \right)\ln\left( \frac{1 + \frac{1}{2k+1}}{1 - \frac{1}{2k+1}} \right) = \sum^\infty_{l=1} \frac{1}{\left( 2l+1\right)\left( 2k+1 \right)^{2l}}. $$
2. Then the following inequality for the lower bound (the upper bound is easily shown by doing the infinite sum, but I am having trouble checking the first inequality for the lower bound):
   $$ \frac{1}{12\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)} < \sum^\infty_{k=n} \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)^2}<\epsilon_n < \sum^\infty_{k=n}\sum^\infty_{l=1}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)^{2l}} = \frac{1}{12n}. $$

---

**Details of the derivation**

The logarithm of the factorial can be written as
$$ \ln n! = \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \ln n - n + \left( 1 + \int^n_1\frac{x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}}{x}\mathrm{d}x \right). $$

Let
$$C = \exp\left(1 + \int^\infty_1 \frac{x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}}{x}\mathrm{d}x \right) $$
and
$$\epsilon_n = -\int^\infty_n \frac{x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}}{x}\mathrm{d}x. $$
It can be shown that as $n$ approaches infinity,
$$ C \sim \sqrt{2\pi}. $$

The original factorial expression is then
$$ n! = Cn^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n+\epsilon_n} \sim \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n+\epsilon_n}. $$

Knowing this and the series form from (1), and using the inequality from (2), we can bound the approximation as:
$$ \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-n+\frac{1}{12\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right] < n! < \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-n+\frac{1}{12n}\right], $$
and
$$ n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n+\frac{1}{12n}}. $$

Comment: Question 1 : Use the classical Taylor expansion of $\ln(\tfrac{1+x}{1-x})=\operatorname{artanh}(x)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions).

Comment: Question 2: you can use $$\int_n^\infty f(x)dx \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty f(k)$$ I think you can prove strict inequality, too.

Comment: @ChrisLewis shouldn't the lower integration bound be $n-1$? Although this way we get a stricter lower bound that is greater than the upper bound, which is quite weird.

Comment: @Jono94 see for example here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, working the rhs, let $x=\frac 1{2k+1}$

$$\sum^\infty_{l=1} \frac{1}{\left( 2l+1\right)\left( 2k+1 \right)^{2l}}=\sum^\infty_{l=1} \frac{x^{2l}}{\left( 2l+1\right)}=\frac 1 x\sum^\infty_{l=1} \frac{x^{2l+1}}{\left( 2l+1\right)}$$
$$\sum^\infty_{l=1} \frac{x^{2l+1}}{\left( 2l+1\right)}=-x+\sum^\infty_{l=0} \frac{x^{2l+1}}{\left( 2l+1\right)}=\tanh ^{-1}(x)-x$$

Use the logarithmic representation of the hyperbolic arctangent function, replace $x$ by its definition to obtain the lhs.

For the second one, you can improve the bounds (assuming that you do not want to use Stirling series).

Consider
$$F=\log(n!)-\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-n+\frac{1}{12\left(n+a\right)}\right]    \right)$$ and expand
$$F=\frac{a}{12 n^2}-\frac{30 a^2+1}{360 n^3}+\frac{a^3}{12 n^4}-\frac{105 a^4-1}{1260 n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$

Let $a_2$ be the solution of
$$\frac{a}{12 n^2}-\frac{30 a^2+1}{360 n^3}=0$$ that is to say
$$a_2=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n^2-\frac{2}{15}}$$ and then
$$F_2=\frac{1}{1260
   n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$
Let $a_3$ be the solution of
$$\frac{a}{12 n^2}-\frac{30 a^2+1}{360 n^3}+\frac{a^3}{12 n^4}=0$$ that is to say
$$a_3=\frac{n}{3}  \left(2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3}
   \text{csch}^{-1}\left(-\frac{40 \sqrt{2} n^2}{70
   n^2-9}\right)\right)+1\right)$$
which also leads to
$$F_3=\frac{1}{1260
   n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$

So, stay with $a_2$ which is (as one could expect)

$$a_2=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n^2-\frac{2}{15}}=\frac{1}{30 n}+\frac{1}{900 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

and $e^{F_2}$ is a very tight lower bound of $n!$

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to spend some time reading through the improved lower bound you provided though

Comment: How did you expand $F$? And I don’t get why we are using $a_2$ instead of, say, $a_1$ or $a_3$.

Comment: @Jono94. Taylor series. $a_1=0$ and $a_3$ gives the same error as $a_2$.